# Primitive Recursion -- Definition by Cases

Tags: computability

I would like to know if it is allowed to define bounded maximization by primitive recursion and definition by cases in the following way:

\begin{align*}
[\mathrm{max}\,R](x, 0) &= 0,\\
[\mathrm{max}\,R](x, y + 1) &= \left\{\begin{array}{l l}
    y + 1 & \quad \text{if $R(x, y + 1) = true$}\\
    [\mathrm{max}\,R](x, y) & \quad \text{otherwise.}\\
  \end{array}\right.
\end{align*}

In every source I find, maximization is always defined via the characteristic functions of the relation involved and subsequently constructed via bounded sum, so I'm questioning whether my approach actually works.

Edit: Bounded Maximization means, find the maximum $k \leq y$ such that $R(x, k)$ holds and return $0$ if no such $k$ exists.

Thanks

Comment: Also see [Is definition by cases primitive recursive](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551401/) if you're unsure whether the RHS expression of the recursive case is itself p.r.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the definition you presented is a primitive recursive definition of $[\max R]$ if $R$ is already primitive recursive.