# Is definition by cases a primitive recursive function?

Tags: computability, recursion

[Primitive recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Definition) can simulate every single step of a Turing machine. In order to prove this, one has to see that a function defined by [state table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition) is primitive recursive.

Simply speaking, a partial function $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ with finite [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) is always primitive recursive. That is, *if-else* and *switch-case* constructs (in programming languages) can be represented by appropriate primitive recursive functions. How to prove this property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly write down a definition of the conditional function by primitive recursion:

$$ f(c,x,y) = \begin{cases} y & \text{if }c=0 \\ 
                            x & \text{if }c\ge 1 \end{cases} $$

This may not *look* primitive recursive, but nobody says the recursive case actually has to *use* the value of $f(c-1,x,y)$.

If you want a switch with more than two cases, just chain a number of if-then-elses together.

Comment: Oh, this is pretty elegent!
1. So do you mean that $f(c,x,y) = P_3^4(c-1, f(c-1,x,y), x, y) = x$, that is, the iteration of the recursion is just projection to third argument?  
2. How do you go around when you want condition different from $c = 0$, say, $c = 42$ or $c = <other hardcoded constant>$?

Comment: @mathemage: Yes, that's what I mean. For another comparison you first need to implement a function that returns $0$ exactly when its argument is $42$, e.g. as $h(x)=(x\dot-42)+(42\dot-x)$.